# How to read input from excel and write to UI application

Tags: macros, jira

In our application we are using JIRA as defect tracking tool. So we want few inputs to be reading from excel and write it certain fields and dropdown in JIRA
For example:
Priority which is a drop down in JIRA should take values entered in excel (2-High) and enter the value in JIRA
similarly URL is a field in JIRA we should be entering in excel and same should be entered in JIRA.
Is there any sample macros we can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

JIRA provides the REST API so you can write a simple program in any language which will be parsing your Excel file and create a ticket in your instance of JIRA and fill ticket fields with values from Excel. Here is the link to API which shows the basic example of creating JIRA ticket thru their REST API https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs#JIRARESTAPIs-TwoSimpleExamplesofCreatinganIssueinJIRA

Also you may find several plugins in Atlassian Market which may be helpful for you or write your own one. At first sight this one https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/pl.com.tt.jira.plugin.excel2jira is what you are looking for.